# Ignore application pool when migrating from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5 with MSDeploy

Tags: iis, migration, msdeploy, application-pool

I am currently migrating my websites from a Windows Server 2003 (**SourceServer**) with IIS 6 to a Windows Server 2008 R2 (**DestServer**)with IIS 7.5.

I use the **MSDeploy** tool to perform the operation. After checking the dependencies (just *Windows Authentication*, already installed in **DestServer**), I create the package in the **SourceServer**:

> msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/5
>   -dest:package=c:\Site5.zip > WebDeployPackage.log

And I copy it in the **DestServer**. From the **DestServer** I test the deployment by using:

> msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=c:\Site5.zip
>   -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/5 -whatif > WebDeploySync.log

But it gives me an error related to the **missing application pool**. Indeed one of my goals was to tide up the websites, since in the **SourceServer** the person who was responsible for the deployment made quite a mess with naming conventions (both for pools and sites), assigned too many applications (even 10) in a single application pool and so on.

Therefore my goal was to run the site in a dedicated brand new application pool in the **DestServer**. But if MSDeploy does not find in the **DestServer** the application pool with the same very name of the **SourceServer** it does not deploy the package on the **DestServer**.

I also tried to use the command `-enableLink: AppPoolExtension` in MSDeploy in both creation and deployment of the package to get also the Application Pool. The package then installs correctly but, I do not know why, it gives errors in the config file. For instance I cannot enable any kind of Authentication module.

Is there any way to let the MSDeploy ignore the application pool when deploying?

Comment: What errors do you receive if you keep the apppool? And have you read [the IIS.net guide on migrating sites from IIS 6 to 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7-or-above)?

Comment: Thanks. The error is: "Error:  The AppPoolNotFound dependency check found the AppPool 'myPool' to be in use by the source data but not defined in source data or on the destination machine.  Applications referencing this app pool will have configuration issues." I followed that guide to migrate the websites

Comment: What about when you include `enableLink:AppPoolExtension`? What's there error you receive then?

Comment: I have some errors in the web.config because of the different versions of the framework in source and destination server.

Answer (score 0):

```
msdeploy -verb:sync 
         -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1,computerName=original,encryptPassword="pwd",includeAcls=true 
         -disableLink:ContentExtension 
         -dest:package=original.zip,encryptPassword="pwd" 
         -enableLink:AppPool 
         -skip:WebApplication="^.*$"  >original.log
```